# Maven dependency version notation in pom files

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have viewed various tutorials that show how to list a dependency and have noticed the version number for dependencies being written in two different ways.

In one tutorial the version number is written: 3.8.1.

In another tutorial it's written: ${org.springframework-version}

Where/how does it extract the version number in the second example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case `${org.springframework-version}` references a property from the `properties` section of the pom.

```
   <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>3.8.1</org.springframework-version>
   </properties>
```

That approach is useful if you have several dependencies which share the same version number (as it is the case of Spring)

Answer (score 1):

You can define this as a property in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework-version>3.8.1</org.springframework-version>
</properties>
```

The latter is how you reference to this defined version.